# wx-python version incorrect when installing google-app-engine-launcher on Ubuntu

Tags: google-app-engine, wxpython, ubuntu-12.04, launcher

I am trying to install google-app-engine-launcher on Ubuntu 12.04

Following the manual, I installed the launcher in the google-appengine-wx-launcher-read-only directory.

The command python GoogleAppEngineLauncher.py gives this result:
wxPython version incorrect; is 2.6, must be 2.8

I followed the tutorial (http://wiki.wxpython.org/InstallingOnUbuntuOrDebian) installed and setup wxPython 2.8, still I get the same message:
wxPython version incorrect; is 2.6, must be 2.8

I checked with synaptic and there are still  2.6 modules installed, I doubt but don't know if it is used for something. If it is obsolete I don't know how to savely remove it. Is there a way to get it working?

thanks, Mark

Comment: Can you please share the link from which you download the Launcher.py? I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove it with Ubuntu's package manager. Alternatively, you can use wxversion to select which version of wx to use: http://wiki.wxpython.org/MultiVersionInstalls

If you know where Python is installed, you could go in there and remove the wx folder from site-packages. You may need to edit your PATH too. This article may be related: http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=3948 (it's about wxWidgets, but the process should be similar).

If none of that works, ask on the wxPython list. They can help!

Comment: Thank you, I tried removing the 2.6 and reinstalling. Now I get the massage "wxPython is not available" The problem seems to be that there is no package for precise: see at http://apt.wxwidgets.org/dists/
They are looking for a volunteer to maintain the debian - Ubuntu packages for the various distros. There is a possibility to build your own though, I will look into that :)

Comment: Yeah, building your own should work. If you run into issues doing that, just ask for help on the wxPython users group. There are several people there who know how to help with that.